# java send e_mail by javamail using SMTP host server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is the method:

```
  public void sendMail(String mailServer, String from, String to, String subject, String messageBody)
        throws MessagingException, AddressException 
{ 

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer);


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);


    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject(subject);


    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText(messageBody);


    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();


    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);





    message.setContent(multipart);


    Transport.send(message);
    System.err.println("Message Send");

}  






 try {
        sendMail("mail.emailsrvr.com","it@ne.jo","it@ne.jo","!!!!TEST!!!!","TEST MESSAGE FROM JAVA APPLICATION");
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The output is:

```
Dec 20, 2014 9:05:51 AM hd.MainWindow jButton10ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
class com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <it@ne.jo>: Sender address rejected: Access denied

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1141)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:536)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:151)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
at hd.MainWindow.sendMail(MainWindow.java:1493)
at hd.MainWindow.jButton10ActionPerformed(MainWindow.java:1237)
at hd.MainWindow.access$2600(MainWindow.java:28)
at hd.MainWindow$27.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:825)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: whoever had downvoted the question, kindly put some comments

Comment: however its possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131868/how-resolve-address-invalid-exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaMail - Sender Address rejected: Access Denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005837/javamail-sender-address-rejected-access-denied)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [authenticate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpauth).